# regular expression matching - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have a string of html contained in between [marquee][/marquee] tags in the string like so:

```
var s = '[marquee]<p>some html here 1</p>[/marquee][marquee]<p>some html here again 2</p>[/marquee]';
```

what I would like to do is match each one of these marquees to create an array with each marquee as an array element.

What I've tried so far is:

```
var marqueeArray = s.trim().match(/\[marquee\][\s\S]*\[\/marquee\]/g);
```

but all i get back is and array with the length of 1. both marquees end up being included as one string like this:

```
["[marquee]<p>some html here 1</p>[/marquee][marquee]<p>some html here again 2</p>[/marquee]"]
```

what i would like is this:

```
["[marquee]<p>some html here 1</p>[/marquee]", "[marquee]<p>some html here again 2</p>[/marquee]"]
```

eventually i will need to remove the brackets ([marquee] and [/marquee]) from each element and replace with  and join one big string for use in the application. any point in the right direction on that would be great as well.

Comment: Just use `[\s\S]*?`

Comment: You can use `s = s.split(/\[\/?marquee\]/).join("");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to use `?` quantifier to make your search lazy.

Add `?` as mentioned `\[marquee\][\s\S]*`**?**`\[\/marquee\]`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Tz154/1)

Comment: This worked for what I need to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following will match all marquee tags and the content between them.

```
s.match(/(\[marquee\].*?\[\/marquee\])/g);
```

If you want to capture the content *between* the marquee tags you can use the following:

```
var pattern = /\[marquee\](.*?)\[\/marquee\]/g;
var match = pattern.exec(s);
while(match != null){
  console.log(match[1]); // Prints out content between tags
  match = pattern.exec(s);
}
```

Comment: This would have also worked for me. Thank you.